# Getting error with: pbsu & pbrun commands via Plink (command not found)

Tags: shell, vba, unix, ssh, plink

I'm doing automation for run commands via Plink. Below is required step to run command in my environment:

1. Login to unix machine:

   - host: myhost
   - user/pass: myuser/Mypass
2. Use command: `pbsu - uatwrk1`
   (Or command: `pbrun –u uatwrk1 pbksh`)
   ->it will redirect to other machine and some commands to be executed there
3. Run some commands

******Issue*******

(I) When I execute the Plink command line below in CMD, I'll get error:
  The content of `script.txt`:

```
pwd  
pbsu - uatwrk1  
pwd  
runcommand.ksh
```

---

```
plink -ssh myuser@myhost -pw Mypass -m "C:\script.txt" > "C:\log.txt"
```

> Error: "sh: pbrun: command not found"

(II) But it works with command by command:

```
cmd>plink -ssh myuser@myhost -pw Mypass  
$pwd  
$pbsu - uatwrk1  
$pwd  
$runcommand.ksh
```

Please help to to figure out why the command `pbrun` failed on (I) while it worked on (II) ?
I need (I) works as it provides the capture log to check further in my automated application (using VBA).

Thanks a ton for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if in the interactive session (II) you have another environment than in the batch session (I). You must check what `PATH` and current directory you have in the both cases.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I tried to put full path of pbsu command in the script and it worked. It seems there's a different when running commands in script file and run command by command (manually) in interactive session with Plink ? As with interactive type, I don't need to put pbsu command in full path. Can you help me clear it.

Comment: @PhucNguyen: It's possible that for interactive sessions you have other PATH

Comment: I didn't get your idea but  
for interactive session, works fine with command: ($pbsu - uatwrk1)  
, for command string with Plink - command should be: (/usr/local/bin/pbsu - uatwrk1). Otherwise, I'll get error: "command not found". I also get same issue with other commands such as "sh"

Comment: @PhucNguyen: Canyou compare `'echo $PATH'` in both modi (interactive/batch)?

Comment: Hi Igor, the PATH in interactive is /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin, but the PATH in batch is the long list. I'm not sure why they're different. Is there is way to make the PATH in batch session same to the PATH in interactive mode ?

Comment: @PhucNguyen: Could you check your `~/.bashrc`? Can it be that the PATH is set there?

Comment: Thanks Igor, I think you drive me on the right way. My machine uses .profile file (for ksh). I googled and tried statement ($ssh user@remotehost 'command . $HOME/.profile; echo $PATH'). Then I got error: "stty : : not a typewriter". Please help me with the new issue. Thanks.

Comment: @PhucNguyen: You should read `man ksh` about interactive/non-intercative start and about startup scripts of it